# Adding Confirmation box

Tags: php, html, onclick

I'm trying to add an "confirmation box" that says "Are you sure you want to update/delete question?" when I click on my "update" and/or "delete" buttons.

I've already tried adding

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?');"

<input type="submit" value="Add Question" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to update/delete question?');">
```

I provided my two php files. Might not need the whole files but I hope you can understand my issue and help the best that y'all can. thank you.

File: `questions_menu.php`

```
    <?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "basketball_database";
$table = "question_bank";

$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to MYsql");
 //echo "Connected to mysql<br>";

 mysql_select_db("$database")
 or die("Could not select Basketball_database");
 //echo "Connected to database";

      //update when update button pressed
 if(isset($_POST['update'])){
     $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE $table SET question_description='$_POST[description]', option_a='$_POST[option1]', option_b='$_POST[option2]', option_c='$_POST[option3]', answer='$_POST[dropdown]', question_id='$_POST[questionID]'  WHERE question_id='$_POST[hidden]'";

     mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);

 };//end of if statement

  //delete when delete button pressed
 if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
     $DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE question_id='$_POST[hidden]'";

     mysql_query($DeleteQuery, $con);

 };//end of if statement



$mysql = "SELECT * FROM $table";



 $mydata = mysql_query($mysql,$con);

 //create table
 echo "<table border=1
 <tr>
 <th>Question ID</th>
 <th>Question Description</th>
 <th>Option 1</th>
 <th>Option 2</th>
 <th>Option 3</th>
 <th>Answer</th>
 <th>Picture</th>
 <th>Video</th>
 </tr>";

 //insert data into rows
 while($records = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
     echo "<form action=questions_menu.php method=post>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=questionID size=10 value=".$records['question_id']." </td>";
     echo "<td>"."<textarea name=description rows=2 cols=25>".$records['question_description']."</textarea>"."</td>";
     echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=option1 size=18 value=".$records['option_a']." </td>";
     echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=option2 size=15 value=".$records['option_b']." </td>";
     echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=option3 size= 15 value=".$records['option_c']." </td>";
     echo "<td>"."<input type=text name=answer size=15 value=".$records['answer']." </td>";

     echo "<td>"."<input type=hidden name=hidden value=".$records['question_id']." </td>";

     //update button
     echo "<td>"."<input type=submit name=update value=Update onclick=return confirm(Are you sure you want to update/delete question?)"." </td>";
     //delete button
      echo "<td>"."<input type=submit name=delete value=Delete onclick=return confirm(Are you sure you want to update/delete question?)"." </td>";


     echo "</tr>";  

     echo "</form>";//end form

 } echo "</table>";

 mysql_close();
?>  <!-- End of php code-->
```

Comment: *I've already tried adding...* so what's wrong with that?

Comment: Also, your `echo` statements are horrible, you should consider closing the php tags before you render html..

Comment: I'm new into php and html so my skills aren't up to par. I've already tried adding the onclick= return statement to my submit buttons and when I click the submit button, no confirmation box pops up. I just don't know what to do.

Comment: I don't see any on `onclick` event on submit button of `questions_menu.php`, it should work

Comment: Sorry I copied the code from my testing file. It's below the "Insert data in row"... The problem is every time i click the update or delete buttons, data in the row is updated or deleted without confirmation. I hope this helps a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close input tag at following line:

```
echo "<td>"."<input type=submit name=update value=Update onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to update/delete question?\")'>"." </td>";
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

And you need to use put confirm code in single quotes as shown above. And also note the escape sequence used for message text.

Comment: @JordanO'NeaPVAMUSenior you need to add it to before closing double quotes, as shown in the answer. If still it doesn't work please update your question with error you are getting after trying above code.

Comment: It works now. I'm not use to using so many quotations and single quotes in one line.